# Disable HTTP version of site Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, http, https, sitemap, robots.txt

Main site page is https://example.com/. Robots think that http://example.com/ is also main page. How can I disable all http pages from indexing?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have proper redirection set for SSL. Try this.

Go to `Dashboard` `->` `Settings` `->` `General Settings`.

Change WordPress Address (URL) from `http://example.com/` to `https://example.com/`.

> PS : This will redirect you to https version of the website and log you out as well. Do this only when `https` version of your side works or you will have to do some manual changes in order to undo this changes.

You can go ahead an de-index all the `http` links from Google Search Console manager. I would recommend to ask any seo related questions (repercussions) here : https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

It would be a good practice to redirect all http to https using a rewrite rule to.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I've already had `https://example.com/` in settings of WP. Also all HTTP links already redirects on HTTPS. I want to exclude HTTP from indexing using robots.txt or sitemap